# broken `std::promise`s (why do they break when I store many futures before `.get()`ing them?)

Tags: c++, promise, future

I was writing a unit test for my thread pool `pool`. This class has a sum function member stored inside, that it uses over and over again. The input to this sum function is passed in to `work`.

```
unsigned num_tries(1e3);
std::vector<std::future<double>> futs;
for(size_t i = 0; i < num_tries; ++i){
    futs.push_back( std::move( pool.work(std::vector<double>{1.0, 1.0, 1.0})) );
}
```

So, this thread pool should take the sum of three ones over and over again. The function returns a `std::future<double>`. So far so good.

However, when I try to `.get()` the values once all the computation is finished, I get a `std::future_error: Broken promise` error.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < num_tries; ++i){                            
    std::cout << futs[i].get() << "\n";
}
```

Why is this? I thought `.get()` was blocking.

My guess: `pool` only stores one `std::promise` that keeps getting re-assigned every time `work` is called. Everything works when I stick both of these lines in a single `for` loop, so that `.get()` is always called before the subsequent `std::promise` is made. In other words, there are no errors with this code:

```
unsigned num_tries(1e3);
std::future<double> fut;
for(size_t i = 0; i < num_tries; ++i){
    fut =  pool.work(std::vector<double>{1.0, 1.0, 1.0});
    std::cout << fut.get() << "\n";
}
```

If this is the case, how can I prevent others from making the same mistake that I am making now? Have it return a double and block inside, I suppose would be one way.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: We can't tell you what you've done wrong in your pool code if we can't see it.